# Neo4j - Count distinct nodes

Tags: neo4j, count, cypher, relationship

I have this kinds of relationships:

```
(:User)<-[:MENTIONS]-(:Tweet)-[:ABOUT]->(:Topic)
```

I would like to count all the users mentioned in the tweets regarding some topic.

With the following query

```
match (n:Topic)<--(t:Tweet)-[:MENTIONS]->(u:User) 
where n.name='politics'
return distinct count(u)
```

all I get is the relationships count.

What I would like to get is, instead, the number of users mentioned (without duplicates if a user is mentioned several times).
How is that possible?

Comment: Have you forgot the `[:ABOUT]` relationship?

Comment: it's not important in this case, because it's the only relationship between tweet and topic

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try putting distinct inside `count` function, this way:

```
match (n:Topic)<-[:ABOUT]-(t:Tweet)-[:MENTIONS]->(u:User) 
where n.name='politics'
return count(distinct u)
```

Comment: @sirdan You are welcome! If this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Of course I accept it, I was waiting some minutes because the system didn't allow me to accept it before 10 minutes.